# individual product download link

Tags: php, hyperlink, download, bigcommerce

Following situation:
We use the bigcommerce webshop and I only have access to the template files, not to the PHP files of bigcommerce itself. We sell tickets that you can print (there is an individual barcode on each ticket!), to do this we have a ticket generator that generates a PDF file with all the necessary information (the generator access the API to gather all the necessary information).

The problem: The download link for the product is not changeable to the "ticket generator". It would be great if the buyer can immediately click on "Download Product" (Like it is right now, but there is only a static image file behind this link) and sees the right ticket (the dynamic created one).

Solution: There would be an easy solution, .. if I can change the download link for all products to point to the "ticket generator" php file. I could do this with a static link (by modifying the template), but the link has to be dynamic (add orderid, productid and some security hash values to the URL.)

Anyone an idea how I could solve this?

regards
Simon

Answer (score 0):

the download link autogenerated. It is not possible to change that link to best of my knowledge. Product/downloads only have a GET resource on them.